# Remove All Non-Alphabetic Characters, Preserve Spaces in String

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not a programmer. I'm an artist learning Python for an art installation I'm making. I've made it this far on Youtube and Stackoverflow.

That said...

I'm getting text from an API, which I then display in a label. The raw text looks like this:

`{"word":"hello","synonyms":["hi","how-do-you-do","howdy","hullo"]}` , The words change depending on user-input.

I want to only display the words within the brackets, without punctuation. After much Stackoverflow, I discover `re.sub(r"\W", "", text, flags=re.I)`(dear God, I don't know what it means, just that w,W means alphabetic/Non). Which gives me:

`"wordhellosynonymshihowdoyoudohowdyhullo`

*sigh*. How do I preserve my spaces? I think I can strip the first 17 words on my own.

Full code (I'm embarrassed). I know parts of it are broken, I'm putting out one fire at a time. The final project is a program that returns synonyms of user-entered words and then asks the user if the ouput is correct. The result will eventually be display in a graph. The output is *intentionally* wrong sometimes, I don't need this fixed.

'''

````
import requests
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import font
import re
import string


root = Tk ()
Graph = Tk ()

def create_grid(event=None):
    w = c.winfo_width() # Get current width of canvas
    h = c.winfo_height() # Get current height of canvas
    c.delete('grid_line') # Will only remove the grid_line

    # Creates all vertical lines at intevals of 100
    for i in range(0, w, 100):
        c.create_line([(i, 0), (i, h)], tag='grid_line')

    # Creates all horizontal lines at intevals of 100
    for i in range(0, h, 100):
        c.create_line([(0, i), (w, i)], tag='grid_line')

c = Canvas(Graph, height=1600, width=1600, bg='white')
c.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

c.bind('<Configure>', create_grid)






#lets you press enter for query instead of clicking w mouse
#the "forget" objects deletes the button and the widget.
# Should figure out either a timeout, restart, or back-button.
def onReturn(*args):
    command = Buttonclick()
    Button.pack_forget(Button_1)
    Entry_1.pack_forget()
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Help!","This installation measures the accuracy of synoymns delivered. In the next window, please select 'yes' if your synonym was correct, and 'no' if it was not.")
    answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Accurate?", "Synonym Accurate?")

## Immeidately above and below is the messagebox text. Will eventually connect to a grid.

    if answer == "yes":
        print("thanks!")
    if answer == "no":
        print("FUCK. Sorry.")

    ### Add yes/no actions for message box!

#Gets the user entry when button is pressed, either by mouse or enter key.
def Buttonclick():
    Entry_1.get()


       # this is the API that gets the synonyms - the url must be www.URLURLURL.URL.com/words/ENTRY HERE!!/typeof
        #DO NOT FUCKING TOUCH THIS. IT'S MAGIC AND I DO NOT CONTROL IT.
    url = "https://wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com/words/"+Entry_1.get()+"/synonyms"

    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "myapikey"
    }

    punct = "!#$%&'()*+,-./:;?@[\]^_`{|}~"

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers,)


    newstring = response

    text = response.text


    print(response.text)
    label = Label(root, text= re.sub(r"\W", "", text, flags=re.I), font="helv 18", bg="black", fg="white", )
    label.pack()
    testing = Button(root, text="Press Spacebar to Restart", font="Helv 24", bg="red", fg="white",command=Spacebar)
    testing.bind("<space>",Spacebar)
    testing.pack()


def Spacebar():
    root.configure(background='blue')
    root.geometry("1600x1600+50+50")
    Entry_1 = Entry(root, bg="black", fg="White", font="Helv 48")
    Entry_1.bind("<space>", onReturn)
    Entry_1.pack(expand=1)
    Button_1 = Button(root, text="Type Word, Press Enter For Synonym", font="Helv 24", bg="blue", fg="white", command=Buttonclick)
    Button_1.pack(fill=X, expand=1)
    Label.forget()



#Initial button and text entry box, sized correctly.
root.configure(background='blue')
root.geometry("1600x1600+50+50")
Entry_1 = Entry(root, bg="black", fg="White", font="Helv 48")
Entry_1.bind("<Return>", onReturn)
Entry_1.pack(expand=1)
Button_1 = Button(root, text="Type Word, Press Enter For Synonym", font="Helv 24", bg="blue", fg ="white", command=Buttonclick)
Button_1.pack(fill=X, expand=1)

root.mainloop() ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Json serialization for this work. From API you are getting response in `JSON` format.

```
import json 

response = <your response>
json_obj = json.loads(response)
strvalue = " ".join(json_obj["synonyms"])
print(strvalue)
```

Json example : https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! Very satisfying and simple.

Answer (score 4):

What you got is a JSON string. You need to parse the JSON. There is a library for that.

```
import json
text = '{"word":"hello","synonyms":["hi","how-do-you-do","howdy","hullo"]}'
data = json.loads(text)
print(" ".join(data["synonyms"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The object you got is called a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation) or a `dict` and it's awesome.

if you assign it to a variable like this:

```
a = {"word":"hello","synonyms":["hi","how-do-you-do","howdy","hullo"]}
```

you can then reference them like this:

```
for item in a['synonyms']:
     print(item)
```

It would be really useful in order for SO to help you to provide what's called a full working example of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Since he seemed to be able to use a regex on the entire thing, I doubt it's already a JSON. Maybe add something about serialization to your code, because otherwise it'll inevitably lead to another post :)

Comment: Wow, I'm not used to people being polite in forums! Guess I haven't been off Reddit in a minute. 

Do you mean an explanation of my project, or my full code?

Comment: @TomMP my theory is that he called an online API which returned a json and then he stringified it

Comment: @Tooluser r/learnpython is pretty useful! and yes, it would help if you provided your code and tried to explain in a bit more detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: @vencaslac Sure, I was just going by what we have here. Let's hope you're right. @Tooluser should you encounter an error like `TypeError: string indices must be integers`, call `json.loads()` on your text first as is suggested in another answer.

Comment: @vencaslac, I edited my post with my full code and project. Gulp.

Comment: @Tooluser it's totally fine since this is not your specialty, but that's probably *too* much code for what you want us to solve. Calling it a full working example is misleading, as it's usually called a [Minimal Working Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example). It's the least amount of code we need to reproduce your problem. Again, this is difficult for you to judge. From what I can tell, following this answer will lead you to the error I described above. Try ilmiacs solution, it should do what you want.

Comment: Hahah, you're very kind, and correct. A programmer I am not. 

You were correct again that I'd get the TypeError, and correct in triplicate about ilmiacs solution (it worked). Thank you for a great intro to SO.

Comment: @Tooluser make sure you mark his solution as an answer so he gets the credit

Comment: @vencaslac, rather embarrassingly... I meant Sornalingam. Their answer worked for me.

Oops.